# Wrong DB record being updated

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, sql-update

Maybe I'm tired, maybe I'm just going about this wrong but what ever the case something isn't right.

When the checkbox is ticked the DB is updated, but the $id is ignored and only the first record with an empty pu_time column is updated. What is supposed to happen is when the checkbox is ticked the current time is inserted into the corresponding record with the id provided. I can echo the $id, but it is still ignored.

I have successfully made this work with a textbox....

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  dispatch WHERE driver = '' OR pu_time = '' OR do_time = ''";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
            $i = 0;
        $color1 = "#2b2823";
        $color2 = "#333333";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            if($i%2 == 1) {$color = $color1;}
                else {$color = $color2;}

                echo "<tr style='background-color: $color'>";
                echo '<td><input name="id" type="hidden" value="'.$row['id'].'" />'.$row['call_time'].'</td>';
                echo "<td>".$row['start_address']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['end_address']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['phone']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['puat']."</td>";
if (isset($row['pu_time']) === true && empty($row['pu_time']) === true){

                        echo '<td>
                             <form id = "pu_time">
                              <input name="pick_up_time" type="checkbox" value="" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
                            </form></td>';
                                if (isset($_GET['pick_up_time'])){
                                    $pick_up = date('g:ia');
                                    $update_p = "UPDATE dispatch SET pu_time = '{$pick_up}' WHERE id = '{$id}'";
                                    mysql_query($update_p,$con)
                                    or die;
                                    unset($_GET['pick_up_time']);
                                    echo '<script type="text/JavaScript">
                                            window.location.href = "new_index.php";
                                          </script>';
                                    }
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "<td>".$row['pu_time']."</td>";
                            }
```

Comment: mysql functions are deprecated, use mysqli.

Comment: You should really use PDO or mysqli's prepared statements. Concatenation in SQL is very bad, and dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just two changes will fix your problem:

Add the the row ID into a hidden field and then submit:

```
<?php echo '
<td><form id = "pu_time">
    <input name="pick_up_time" type="checkbox" value="" onchange="if(this.checked)this.form.submit()" />
    <input name="rowId" type="hidden" value="'.$id.'" />
</form></td>';
```

And of course, DB update portion will be outside the loop to avoid unnecessary DB call as we are redirecting to a new page (or same page):

```
if (isset($_GET['pick_up_time']) && !empty($_GET['rowId'])){ // must have id;
    $pick_up = date('g:ia');
    $rowId = $_GET['rowId']; //mark this!
    $update_p = "UPDATE dispatch SET pu_time = '{$pick_up}' WHERE id = '{$rowId}'";
    mysql_query($update_p,$con)
    or die;
    unset($_GET['pick_up_time']);
    echo '<script type="text/JavaScript">
        window.location.href = "new_index.php";
      </script>';
}

 //and then write your code what is currently in the first line: $sql = "SELECT * FROM  dispatch WHERE dr ...... and so;
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank You, THANK YOU!! I had been goofing with that for way to long... Now I can go to bed! ;)